# Shortest path between two nodes in a graph based on a different condition

Tags: graph, dijkstra, adjacency-list, breadth-first-search

I was trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-path) problem on Hackerrank. Initially, I was thinking that this would be a straight forward Dijkstra's implementation but this was not to be.

The code I have written is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

typedef struct edge { unsigned int to, length; } edge;

int dijkstra(const vector< vector<edge> > &graph, int source, int target) {
    vector< int > min_distance(graph.size(), INT_MAX);
    min_distance[ source ] = 0;
    std::vector< bool > visited(graph.size(), false);
    set< pair<int,int> > active_vertices;
    active_vertices.insert( {0,source} );
    while (!active_vertices.empty()) {
        int where = active_vertices.begin()->second;
        int where_distance = active_vertices.begin()->first;
        visited[where] = true;
        active_vertices.erase( active_vertices.begin());
        for (auto edge : graph[where])
        {
          if(!visited[edge.to])
          {
            int cost = where_distance | edge.length;
            min_distance[edge.to] = min(cost, min_distance[edge.to]);
            active_vertices.insert({cost, edge.to});
          }
        }
    }
   return min_distance[target];
}

 int main( int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned int n, m, source, target;
        cin>>n>>m;
        std::vector< std::vector<edge> > graph(n, std::vector<edge>());
        while(m--)
        {
            unsigned int from, to, dist;
            cin>>from>>to>>dist;
            graph[from-1].push_back({ to-1, dist});
            graph[to-1].push_back({from-1, dist});
        }
        cin>>source>>target;
        cout<<dijkstra(graph, source-1, target-1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The approach that I have is pretty simple. At each vertex I consume it's outgoing edge and update the `active_vertices` with it's updated cost provided that vertex is not yet visited. Also, a `min_distance` vector keeps track of the minimum distance so far.

But this fails for half the test cases. I am not able to find out why from the input as the input file has a large number of edges and recreating it is quite difficult.

It would be nice if you can help me with what's wrong with my current approach and I'm also a bit confused if it's running time is exponential.
What would be the running time of this code?

Answer (score 0):

You missed this: ***multiple edges are allowed***. As such, you have to choose which edge that you want to use (Not necessarily the one with smallest C).